# Growth functions won't agree - a puzzling result

Tags: python, numpy, math

OK, I'm working from a paper ([Paine et al 2012](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2011.00155.x)) on producing growth functions in Python. The growth functions are expressed in a number of different ways and I will need to use more than one of them (for different applications).

Equation1:[image: Gompertz function expressed as change in mass per change in time] Equation 2: 
[image: Gompertz function expressed as a function of time]

Equation 1 is a Gompertz function expressed as change in mass per change in time, and Equation 2 is the same Gompertz function expressed as a function of total time elapsed. The one calculates the change in mass based on the current mass, and the other calculates the mass based on how long it has been growing for.

I've translated these into python and written some code to check they match (since they are different expressions of the same equation it shouldn't be a problem...)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gompertz_t(m_0, K, r, t):
    return K*(m_0/K)**np.exp(-r*t)

def gompertz_m(m, K, r):
    eq1 = r*m
    eq2 = np.log(K/m)
    return m+eq1*eq2

x = list(range(0,50,1))

m_0 = 0.1 #(must not be equal to zero)

#Set up values for year 0
y_1 = [m_0]
y_2 = [m_0]

for i in x[1:]:
    #And run for x years
    y_1.append(gompertz_m(y_1[-1],50,0.5))
    y_2.append(gompertz_t(y_2[0],50,0.5,i))

# df = pd.DataFrame(index = x)
# df["gompertz_m"] = y_1
# df["gompertz_t"] = y_2
# df.to_clipboard()

fig = plt.figure()
chart = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
chart.plot(x,y_1, label="Gompertz curve (time)")
chart.plot(x,y_2, label="Gompertz curve (mass)")

plt.legend()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However... They don't match. The resulting curves disagree.

[image: A comparison]

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here? I've run into the same issue with other growth curves, so I assume it's a problem with my implementation rather than the original equations.

Comment: what make you think they are the same equation?

Comment: Table 1 in the paper I linked to (https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/cms/asset/7b7d2707-7e64-4dde-96c4-9ae61be274db/mee3_155_t1.gif)

Comment: they represent different things,  one is dM/dt (the change of mass in time) and the other is the mass differential basis

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid.. As I understand it, the one shows an increment based on y (so yn+1, based on yn), and the other shows the y point based on the value of x? I thought I'd compensated for that - or have I completely misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the difference comes from the fact that equation 1 is the derivative of equation 2.  This means that your loop with an increment of 1 time unit (year) will approximate the change "discretely" with equation 1 while equation 2 yields a continuous value (i.e. the integral of equation 1).   For a better fit you would need to greatly increase the "sampling rate" of equation 1.

To do this you will need to make the function return its true delta value (i.e. not add it to the mass parameter):

```
def gompertz_m(m, K, r):
    eq1 = r*m
    eq2 = np.log(K/m)
    return eq1*eq2           # removed the m +
```

Then increase the sampling rate by applying multiple smaller time intervals.

For example (sampling on a daily basis):

```
for i in x[1:]:
    #And run for x years
    cumMass = y_1[-1]
    for _ in range(365):
        cumMass += gompertz_m(cumMass,50,0.5)/365
    y_1.append(cumMass)
    y_2.append(gompertz_t(y_2[0],50,0.5,i))
```

Comment: Thank you Alain - that's really helpful (I really am getting beyond the limits of my maths skills!)